# Context must not be null

Tags: java, android

I get this error in the LogCat when I try to run the application.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.

This happens when I add the Picasso code in the class.

here is the adpater.Java

It says the Context is null, I have read other posts but I could not find a solution.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>{
private List<App> mApps;
private boolean mHorizontal;
private boolean mPager;
private Context mContext;


public Adapter(Context ctx, boolean horizontal, boolean pager, List<App> apps) {
    mHorizontal = horizontal;
    mApps = apps;
    mPager = pager;
    this.mContext=ctx;
}



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {




        if (mPager) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.adaper_pager, parent, false));
        } else {
            return mHorizontal ? new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.adapter, parent, false)) :
                    new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.adapter_vertical, parent, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        App app = mApps.get(position);
        //holder.imageView.setImageResource(app.getDrawable());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(app.getLink()).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.nameTextView.setText(app.getName());
        holder.ratingTextView.setText(String.valueOf(app.getRating()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mApps.size();
    }



    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView nameTextView;
        public TextView ratingTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.igOne);
            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
            ratingTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
        }

    }

}
```

Please Help. some say it is because the imageView is null. I have no idea about that.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Context mContext = MainActivity.this;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 0;


    public static final String ORIENTATION = "orientation";

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private boolean mHorizontal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate: Starting MainActivity");
        setupBottomNavigationView();


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mHorizontal = true;
        } else {
            mHorizontal = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(ORIENTATION);
        }

        setupAdapter();

    }


    /**
     * Setup Bottom Navigation View
     */

    private void setupBottomNavigationView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: Setting up Bottom Navigation View");
        BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_bar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, bottomNavigationViewEx);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);


    }

    public void click(View v) {
        Intent mIntent = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.serve:
                mIntent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
                break;

            case R.id.imageButton2:
                mIntent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }


    ///////////

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(ORIENTATION, mHorizontal);
    }

    private void setupAdapter() {
        List<App> apps = getApps();

        SnapAdapter snapAdapter = new SnapAdapter();
        if (mHorizontal) {
            snapAdapter.addSnap(new Snap(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, "Snap Start", apps));
            snapAdapter.addSnap(new Snap(Gravity.START, "Snap Middle", apps));
            snapAdapter.addSnap(new Snap(Gravity.END, "Snap End", apps));
            snapAdapter.addSnap(new Snap(Gravity.CENTER, "Pager snap", apps));
        } else {
            snapAdapter.addSnap(new Snap(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, "Snap center", apps));
            snapAdapter.addSnap(new Snap(Gravity.TOP, "Snap top", apps));
            snapAdapter.addSnap(new Snap(Gravity.BOTTOM, "Snap bottom", apps));
        }

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(snapAdapter);
    }

    private List<App> getApps() {

        List<App> apps = new ArrayList<>();
        apps.add(new App("Google+", "http://uupload.ir/files/aud7_brickone.jpg", 4.6f));

        return apps;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        return false;
    }


}
```

**SnapAdapter**

```
public class SnapAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SnapAdapter.ViewHolder> implements GravitySnapHelper.SnapListener {

    public static final int VERTICAL = 0;
    public static final int HORIZONTAL = 1;
    private Context mContext;



    private ArrayList<Snap> mSnaps;
    // Disable touch detection for parent recyclerView if we use vertical nested recyclerViews
    private View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    };

    public SnapAdapter() {
        mSnaps = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addSnap(Snap snap) {
        mSnaps.add(snap);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Snap snap = mSnaps.get(position);
        switch (snap.getGravity()) {
            case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
                return VERTICAL;
            case Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL:
                return HORIZONTAL;
            case Gravity.START:
                return HORIZONTAL;
            case Gravity.TOP:
                return VERTICAL;
            case Gravity.END:
                return HORIZONTAL;
            case Gravity.BOTTOM:
                return VERTICAL;
        }
        return HORIZONTAL;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = viewType == VERTICAL ? LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter_snap_vertical, parent, false)
                : LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter_snap, parent, false);

        if (viewType == VERTICAL) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view).setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        }

        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Snap snap = mSnaps.get(position);
        holder.snapTextView.setText(snap.getText());

        if (snap.getGravity() == Gravity.START || snap.getGravity() == Gravity.END) {
            holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(holder
                    .recyclerView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
            holder.recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
            new GravitySnapHelper(snap.getGravity(), false, this).attachToRecyclerView(holder.recyclerView);
        } else if (snap.getGravity() == Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) {
            holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(holder
                    .recyclerView.getContext(), snap.getGravity() == Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL ?
                    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL : LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            holder.recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
            new LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(holder.recyclerView);
        } else if (snap.getGravity() == Gravity.CENTER) { // Pager snap
            holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(holder
                    .recyclerView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
            holder.recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
            new PagerSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(holder.recyclerView);
        } else { // Top / Bottom
            holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(holder
                    .recyclerView.getContext()));
            holder.recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
            new GravitySnapHelper(snap.getGravity()).attachToRecyclerView(holder.recyclerView);
        }


         holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(mContext, snap.getGravity() == Gravity.START
            || snap.getGravity() == Gravity.END
            || snap.getGravity() == Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,
            snap.getGravity() == Gravity.CENTER, snap.getApps()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSnaps.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSnap(int position) {
        Log.d("Snapped: ", position + "");
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView snapTextView;
        public RecyclerView recyclerView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            snapTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.snapTextView);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference, 1) it is LogCat, not CatLog (nitpick) and 2) Don't use snippets for Java code. JavaScript is not the same as Java. Snippets are only for web based code (html, js, css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.
```

> A constructor in Java is a block of code similar to a method that's
>   called when an instance of an object is created.

You should pass [**`Context`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

```
     private Context mContext;

    public Adapter(Context ctx,boolean horizontal, boolean pager, List<App> apps) {
        mHorizontal = horizontal;
        mApps = apps;
        mPager = pager;
        this.mContext=ctx; // Call here


}
```

**Logcat Throws**

> the error is: Error:(110, 40) error: constructor Adapter in class
>   Adapter cannot be applied to given types; required:
>   boolean,boolean,List,Context found: boolean,boolean,List
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

**Pass Value LIKE**

```
new Adapter(Your_Activity.this, boolean, boolean , List<App>);
```

Comment: I did that now get an error on another class called SnapAdpater: 

holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(snap.getGravity() == Gravity.START
                || snap.getGravity() == Gravity.END
                || snap.getGravity() == Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,
                snap.getGravity() == Gravity.CENTER, snap.getApps()));
    }

the error is: Error:(110, 40) error: constructor Adapter in class Adapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: boolean,boolean,List<App>,Context
found: boolean,boolean,List<App>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: @J.Doe add this question section

Comment: @J.Doe you also need to add the context argument to the constructor. The error is because you pass `(Context, boolean, boolean, List<App>)` but the constructor still is `(boolean, boolean, List<App>)`

Comment: @LunarWatcher Well elaborate

Comment: @LunarWatcher I did what you said. my question is now updated. but still i see this error :                                                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.
in logcat.

Comment: Is the context you pass not null? If you pass null you will get the exception

Comment: Thank you so much @LunarWatcher and IntelliJ Amiya. It worked.

Comment: @J.Doe Glad to hear . If this answer helpful for your given problem you can accept this answer `(Click on Right Sign)`.

Answer (score 2):

Call Adapter like this

```
  Adapter  mAdapter = new Adapter (Youractivity_name.this, boolean, boolean , list);
```

and change the constructor to

```
 public Adapter(Context context ,boolean horizontal, boolean pager, List<App> apps) {
    mHorizontal = horizontal;
    mApps = apps;
    mPager = pager;
    mContext = context;
}
```